# I have multiple MySql installed on my machine, how do I choose which one to use?

Tags: mysql

Title is a little confusing, but I installed mysql using brew, and somehow there's another one when I `which mysql`

which shows `/usr/local/bin/mysql`. I assume that's another installment

I'm trying to use the brew one when I just type in `mysql` with more commands followed. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the path for the MySQL instance you want to run to your PATH variable.  If your shell is bash then you can add the MySQL path to your `.bashrc` file:

```
PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/your/mysql
```

You should also remove any other MySQL instances you see in the PATH.  Now next time when you use `mysql` from the command line Linux should pick up on the one you added to the PATH.

Read the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/setting-environment-variables.html) for more information.

Comment: @Tim-Biegelesen right now `which mysql` returns `/usr/local/bin/mysql` and I want to set it to `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql`. Does that consider _instances you see in the PATH_?

Comment: Did you read the article I cited?  Did you update your PATH?  Yes, you need to add `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql` to your PATH.

Comment: Yes I updated that. Even restarted to make sure it takes effect. It's not doing that though. I'm trying to find out why still

Comment: Echo the PATH to the console: `echo $PATH` ... what do you see?

Comment: `/usr/local/Cellar:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:mysql56/5.6.27` I'm not familiar with this kind of representation sorry

Comment: Edit your `$PATH` variable and add `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql` to the path.  Also remove the `mysql56/5.6.27` entry.

Comment: `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql`, is there anyway i can revert it back? I rather have all the commands instead of a working mysql. I'll find another way to do it probably. right now none of my editors work

Comment: You removed everything.  This is what you want: `/usr/local/Cellar:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:usr/local/Cellar/mysql`

Comment: Is there anyway i can revert it? none of my editors (vi, vim, whatever) works now...

Comment: `export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:usr/local/Cellar‌​/mysql`